# object/array comparison shorthand in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript, list-comprehension, destructuring

CoffeeScript has a lot of useful shorthand regarding arrays and objects with comprehensions and destructuring. is there a quick shorthand for comparing entire objects or multiple properties thereof? i.e.

activity.date() is selected.date() and activity.month() is selected.month()

would be something a little like

activity[date(), month()] is selected[date(), month()]

I haven't seen anything like that in the docs but I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any such functionality in CoffeeScript itself, but the [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library includes an [`isEqual`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) function for this:

```
var moe   = {name : 'moe', luckyNumbers : [13, 27, 34]};
var clone = {name : 'moe', luckyNumbers : [13, 27, 34]};
moe == clone;
=> false
_.isEqual(moe, clone);
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's nothing like that, even more for function calls. You can use underscore's isEqual to achieve that.